# not entering the condition if(intent.resolve(getPackageManager()){} neither else{}

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-intent, android-studio

Hey I want my app to locate someone on a map so I made an intent but it's not working and I've no error so I'm a bit lost. I think I've no app that can perform a map location on my emulator but even then I should have that said in my logs. Here is the code:

```
private void openLocationInMap(){
    Log.d("map","in fct");
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final String BASE_URL ="geo:0,0?q=";
    Log.d("map","1");
    String locationData = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.pref_location_key),
            getString(R.string.pref_location_default));
    Log.d("map","2");
    Uri uriGeolocalisation =  Uri.parse(BASE_URL).buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter("q", locationData).build();
    Log.d("map","3");
    Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(uriGeolocalisation);
    Log.d("map","4");
    if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        Log.d("map", "in if");
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        Log.d("map", "couldn't open intent");
    }
    Log.d("map","5");
}
```

And in my log debug I get :

in fct, 1,2,3,4.

Edit: if that can help it works on my phone but still not working on the emulator. I'm guessing it's because I don't have google map on my emulator but still I should see something in the logs which I don't.